# Function that takes a data frame, pulls a column, performs logic, and returns 5 new columns appended to the data frame -- assistance needed

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, function, automation

I can use the below code to perform my original task--taking responses from a column in a pandas data frame, reorganizing, and adding to the data frame.  For the sake of efficiency (because there are 12 columns), I'm looking to create a function that does the following:

```
df['Col1_OnTime'] = np.where((df['Col_1']=='Past Week')|(df['Col_1']=='Past Month'),'On-Time','Not On-Time')
df['Col1_Late'] = ['Year Late' if z == 'Within 12 Months' else 'Less than 12 months' for z in df['Col_1']]
df['Col1_OverAYear'] = ['Over Year' if z == 'Over a year' else 'Less than a year' for z in df['Col_1']]
df['Col1_Default'] = ['Default' if z == 'Over 2 years' else 'Potential Collections' for z in df['Col_1']]
df['Col1_Collections'] = ['Collections' if z == 'Over 3 years' else 'ERROR' for z in df['Col_1']]
```

The above code works by inputting the column for block of code.  I'd like to create a function where I can write: function(column, data frame) and return the same set of logic with the appended data frame, using the column name + _str attached.  I've tried the following:

```
def Status(x, y): 
    y['x_1']= np.where((y['x']=='Past Week')|(y['x']=='Past Month'),'On-Time','Not On-Time')
    y['x_2'] = ['Year Late' if z == 'Within 12 Months' else 'Less than 12 months' for z in y['x']]
    y['x_3'] = ['Over Year' if z == 'Over a Year' else 'Less than a year' for z in y['x']]
    y['x_4'] = ['Default' if z == 'Over 2 years' else 'Potential Collections' for z in y['x']]
    y['x_5'] = ['Collections' if z == 'Over 2 Years' else 'ERROR' for z in y['x']]
    return y
```

I'm an amateur with Python past the basics and research models, but would greatly appreciate help!

Comment: Use `y[x]` and not `y['x']` i.e. remove the quotes around `x`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.